# AppleScript parsing html from site

Tags: parsing, applescript, text-extraction

What I'm trying to do is to get the names of all TV shows on this Wikipedia page.

Ok, so I did this first:

```
property showsWebList : {}

tell application "Safari"
    set loadDelay to 2 -- in seconds; test for your system
    make new document at end of every document
    set URL of document 1 to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_by_name"
    delay loadDelay
    set nrOfUls to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('mw-content-text').querySelectorAll('ul').length;" in document 1
    set nrOfUls to nrOfUls - 1 as number
    log nrOfUls
    repeat with ws from 1 to nrOfUls
        delay loadDelay
        set nrOfLis to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('mw-content-text').getElementsByTagName('UL')[" & ws & "].querySelectorAll('li').length;" in document 1
        set nrOfLis to nrOfLis - 1 as number
        log nrOfLis

        repeat with rs from 0 to nrOfLis
            delay 0.3
            set aShow to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('mw-content-text').getElementsByTagName('UL')[" & ws & "].getElementsByTagName('LI')[" & rs & "].getElementsByTagName('I')[0].getElementsByTagName('A')[0].innerHTML;" in document 1
            if aShow is not "" or "missing value" then
                copy aShow to end of showsWebList
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

And this works exactly how I want it to. The problem is that it takes 15 minutes until it's done and you gotta have the safari document in front the whole time. So my thought was to pick up the whole code and parse it. Not that easy. This is how my code looks now:

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document at end of every document
    set URL of document 1 to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_by_name"

    delay 4

    set orgHTML to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('mw-content-text').innerHTML;" in document 1
    set orgHTML to orgHTML as text
    set readyText to my extractBetween(orgHTML, "<li><i><a ", "</a></i></li>")
    log (item 0 of readyText)
    set removeArray to my extractBetween(readyText, "href", ">")
    set completeArray to {}
    repeat with rt from 0 to (count readyText)
        repeat with ra from 0 to (count removeArray)
            if (item ra of removeArray) is in (item rt of readyText) then
                set completeName to trim_line((item rt of readyText), (item ra of removeArray), 1)
                set end of completeArray to completeName
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    log completeArray

end tell

on extractBetween(SearchText, startText, endText)

    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters -- save them for later.

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startText -- find the first one.

    set liste to text items of SearchText

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endText -- find the end one.

    set extracts to {}

    repeat with subText in liste

        if subText contains endText then

            copy text item 1 of subText to end of extracts

        end if

    end repeat

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid -- back to original values.

    return extracts

end extractBetween

on trim_line(this_text, trim_chars, trim_indicator)
    -- 0 = beginning, 1 = end, 2 = both
    set x to the length of the trim_chars
    -- TRIM BEGINNING
    if the trim_indicator is in {0, 2} then
        repeat while this_text begins with the trim_chars
            try
                set this_text to characters (x + 1) thru -1 of this_text as string
            on error
                -- the text contains nothing but the trim characters
                return ""
            end try
        end repeat
    end if
    -- TRIM ENDING
    if the trim_indicator is in {1, 2} then
        repeat while this_text ends with the trim_chars
            try
                set this_text to characters 1 thru -(x + 1) of this_text as string
            on error
                -- the text contains nothing but the trim characters
                return ""
            end try
        end repeat
    end if
    return this_text
end trim_line
```

Not that smooth and not working. Somehow it seems like I can't get the items out of the list, because it doesn't see it as a list item. Can someone help me out?

Cheers

Comment: Hi, In your first script : Remove `delay ..` and `log ..` within the loops, as they are useless, it only takes 2.5 seconds to get the names of all TV shows (of course after that Wikipedia page is loaded)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a different approach. DL the source, and then just grab the title between tags. The whole script takes under two seconds. Start with:

```
property baseURL : "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_by_name"
set rawHTML to do shell script "curl '" & baseURL & "'"
set preTag to "\" title=\"" -- " title="
set otid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to preTag
set rawList to text items of rawHTML
set nameList to {}
repeat with eachLine in rawList
    set theOff to offset of ">" in eachLine
    set thisName to text 1 thru (theOff - 2) of eachLine
    -- add some error checking here to skip the opening non-title hits, and to fine-tune the precise title string
    set nameList to nameList & return & thisName
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to otid
return nameList
```

Add a little error checking, and tweak which preTag and postTag fits best.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make use of a specialized 3rd-party tool for this task, which can greatly speed things up.

Here's a solution using the [multi-platform web-scraping CLI xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

A shell command to demonstrate its brevity and speed (takes less than 1 sec. on my system) - extracts all show names from the page:

```
xidel -e '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul/li/i/a' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_by_name
```

An equivalent AppleScript snippet - be sure to fill in the path to where you place `xidel` on your system below:

```applescript
set targetUrl to "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_by_name"

set xPathExpr to "//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/ul/li/i/a"

# Fill in the path to `xidel` on your system here:
set xidelPath to "/path/to/xidel"

# Perform scraping and convert result into an AppleScript list.
set showNames to paragraphs of ¬
  (do shell script ¬
    quoted form of xidelPath & " -e " & quoted form of xPathExpr & " " & ¬
    quoted form of targetUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, use javascript to get the names without any AppleScript loop.

The javascript script takes less than one second to get the names.

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document at end of every document with properties {URL:"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_by_name"}
    delay 2 -- in seconds; test for your system

    set showsWebList to do JavaScript "var a=new Array();var ul=document.getElementById('mw-content-text').querySelectorAll('UL');  for (var i=1;i<ul.length;i++){li=ul[i].querySelectorAll('LI'); for (var j=0; j< li.length; j++){try {var t=li[j].getElementsByTagName('I')[0].getElementsByTagName('A')[0].innerText; a.push(t)} catch(e) {}}} a;" in document 1
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

curl/sed/perl solution:

```
do shell script "curl 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_by_name' | sed -n '/0-9/,/NewPP/p' | sed -n '/^<li/ s/^.*title=.\\([^\"]*\\).*$/\\1/p' | perl -n -mHTML::Entities -e ' ; print HTML::Entities::decode_entities($_);'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution using awk using a very simple script. If the line begins with `<li><i>` then remove html tags (gsub) and then print it. Then by using `every paragraph of` the return separated output is converted into a list.

```
set theURL to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_by_name"
every paragraph of (do shell script "curl " & theURL & " | awk '/^\\<li\\>\\<i\\>/{gsub(\"<[^>]*>\", \"\");print}'")
```